# installing sdl2 on vscode mac failing

Tags: visual-studio-code, homebrew, sdl-2

I am trying to install sdl2 on vscode mac with brew command but it's not working and I am not sure why. Below is the error message that I get.

```
brew install sdl2
Updating Homebrew...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> New Casks
affinity-designer                                                                     maxon
==> Updated Casks
Updated 3 casks.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```